# Best algorithm to find the next higher number in perl

Tags: algorithm, perl

I tried to find previous threads similar to my question but didn't find.

Consider a function which gets an array and a number. I would like to find the next higher number.

Example:

Input: `arr = {2,5,3,8,15,10}, number = 6`

Output: `8` because `6 < 8`.

What is the best algorithm to do it in Perl?

Edit: What I tried:

```
my @arr = (2,5,3,8,15,10);
my $number = 6;
my $next_largest = 10000000;
foreach my $val (@arr) {
    if($number < $val && $next_largest > $val) {
        $next_largest = $val;
    }
}

if(defined($next_largest)) {
    print $next_largest."\n";
}
```

Is there a way without declaring `$next_largest = 10000000`? it doesn't look very good and it doesn't handle the case of value higher than this value. Also if I try `$next_lergest` without a number, it doesn't work.

By best I meant - best looking (time isn't important so much).

Comment: Scan the array and keep track of the smallest element larger than the number (if any). There are quite a few ways to do this; what have you tried? If the input array were already sorted, a binary search would be fastest, but that doesn't appear to apply. Also, please define what you mean by "best".

Comment: @TedHopp, I edited my question. please take a look.

Comment: Are the numbers in the array always sorted?

Answer (score 7):

```
use List::Util 'min';
my @arr = (2,5,3,8,15,10);
my $number = 6;
my $next_largest = min grep $_ > $number, @arr;

if(defined($next_largest)) {
    print $next_largest."\n";
}
```

Comment: If the array is always sorted then you can write just `my $next_largest = first { $_ > $number } @arr`. (`first` is also in `List::Util`)

Comment: @Borodin - Based on OP's example data, the array is not necessarily sorted.

Comment: @TedHopp: Ah. I hadn't spotted the last two values!

Answer (score 0):

First, sort the array in numerical ascending order. Then loop through elements in array, until a higher number is found.

```
my $input_number = 6;

my @array = (2, 5, 3, 8, 15, 10);
my @sorted_array = sort { $a <=> $b } @array;

my $found = 0;
my $next_number;

foreach (@sorted_array) {
    my $loop_number = $_;

    if ($loop_number > $input_number) {
        $next_number = $loop_number;
        $found = 1;
        last;
    }
}

if ($found == 1) {
    print "next higher number for " + input_number + " is: " + next_number;
} else {
    print "no next higher number found";
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast replay. is it possible without sorting? please look at my edit.

Comment: If you're going to the bother of sorting, it would be faster to then do a binary search instead of looping. But overall this is going to be slower because sorting alone is O(n log n) and the problem can be solved in a simple O(n) scan. Plus you destroy the original array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$number` as a sentinel value:

```
my @arr = (2,5,3,8,15,10);
my $number = 6;
my $next_largest = $number;
foreach (@arr) {
    if($number < $_ && ($next_largest == $number || $next_largest > $_)) {
        $next_largest = $_;
    }
}

if($next_largest > $number) {
    print $next_largest."\n";
}
```

This eliminates the arbitrary large value in your code and only prints a result if an element strictly greater than `$number` was found.

Note: The [answer by @ysth](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50785555/535871) is much more elegant, but mine may be a bit more memory efficient.

Comment: It doesn't work (tried to run it) because the one the first iteration the if statement actually checks : `if(6 < $_ && 6 > $_)` - always false.

Comment: @TTaJTa4 - Oops. Yeah, I left out the special treatment needed for the sentinel value.

Comment: Is there a way to fix it? That is the way I need it.

Answer (score 0):

This does it too:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my @arr = (2,5,3,8,15,10);
my $number = 6;
my $next_largest = (sort {$a <=> $b} grep {$_ > $number} @arr)[0];
if(defined($next_largest)) {
    print $next_largest."\n";
}
```